# A question about essential representation in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation of a book "C*-algebras Finite-Dimensional Approximations" below:

[Definition 1.7.4](http://books.google.com/books?id=F_kjj0teG2IC&pg=PA19). A representation $\pi: A \rightarrow B(H)$ is called *essential* if $\pi(A)$ contains no nonzero compact operators. ($A$ is a C*-algebra.)

**Essential representations are easy to construct: if $\pi: A\rightarrow B(H)$ is any representation, then its infinite inflation (i.e., the direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\pi$) will be essential.**

I can not understand why the construction above is essential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assertion is that for any $x\in B(H)$, the operator $\bigoplus x$ is not compact when the sum is infinite. This new operator acts on an infinite direct sum of Hilbert spaces. The image of the unit ball $H_1$ will be the direct sum of $xH_1$ (you can play with the vectors that have a single nonzero direct summand), which is not compact.

Comment: I am sorry, could you explain "The image of the unit ball H1 will be the direct sum of xH1 (you can play with the vectors that have a single nonzero direct summand)" in more detail ?

Comment: Suppose you have two. Then you can do $$x\oplus x\,\begin{bmatrix}\xi_1\\ \xi_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\xi_1\\ x\xi_2\end{bmatrix},$$ so the image of $x\oplus x$ is $xH\oplus xH$. Thus if $x$ has rank $n$, say,  then $x\oplus x$ has rank $2n$. What I said above is the "infinitely - many" version of this.

Comment: Yeah, I know this, but what leads $\oplus x$ not compact?

Comment: Take a non-zero element $\xi\in xH$. Then, for any $c\in\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, $\bigoplus_n c_n\xi$ is in the image of $\bigoplus x$. In other words, the image of $\bigoplus x$ contains a copy of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. So we can find a sequence in the unit ball of the image with no convergent subsequence, which implies that $\bigoplus x$ is not compact.

Comment: So, you mean that, for arbitrary $c\in l^{2}(N)$, the $\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} |c_{i}| < M$. So we take a non-zero element $\xi$ such that $||\xi|| \leq 1/M$ and then the sequence $$(c_{1}\xi, 0, 0,...)$$ $$(0, c_{2}\xi, 0, ...)$$ $$....$$ is in the unit ball  with no convergent subsequence, right? Indeed, the "infinitely many" here is countable?

Comment: Countable is enough. But you are mixing the fact that the elements of $\ell^2$ are sequences,  with the consideration of sequences in $\ell^2$ needed to discuss compactness. What I said is that the map $c\mapsto\,\bigoplus_jc_j\xi$ with $\|\xi\|=1$ is an isometric embedding of $\ell^2 (\mathbb N) $ into the image of $\bigoplus x$. But this is unnecessarily complicated.  Just considering the sequence $(\xi,0,\ldots) $, $(0,\xi,0,\ldots) $, $\ldots$ is enough as this sequence cannot have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Do you mean choose the sequence $(\xi, 0,...), (0, \xi,...)$ ($||\xi||=1$) which is in the unit ball of $\oplus H$, then sequence $(x\xi, 0,...), (0, x\xi,...)$ have no convergent subsequence. Right?

Comment: Exactly.$\ \ \ $

Comment: Indeed. $ \ \ \ $